# Cover list.Size() If condition in apex test

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a trigger:

```
trigger UnitTrigger_BeforeU on Unit__c (before update) 
{
List<Unit__c> units= [select id, 
                            Verkocht__c, 
                            Bouwwaarde_appartement__c,
                            BTW__c,
                            Project__c,
                            Bouwwaarde_onderdelen__c,
                            Type__c,
                            Genereer_facturatieschijven__c
                            From Unit__c
                            Where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

List <Onderdeel__c> onderdelen = [Select id, Bouwwaarde__c, Grondwaarde__c, Unit__c from Onderdeel__c Where Unit__c IN:Trigger.newMap.keySet()];     
List<Onderdeel__c> onderdelenToUpdate = new List<Onderdeel__c>{};                     
decimal totaalBouwwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate = 0;
decimal totaalGrondwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate = 0;

For (Unit__c unit: units) 
{
  For(Unit__c u: Trigger.new)
  {
      if(unit.Id == u.Id)
      {
          if(u.Type__c == 'Standaard')
          {
              if(u.Verkocht__c == true && u.Genereer_facturatieschijven__c == true)
              {
                    if (onderdelen.Size() > 0) 
                    {
                        // Totaal bouwwaarde berekenen   
                        for(Onderdeel__c onderdeel: onderdelen)
                        {
                              if(onderdeel.Unit__c == u.id)
                              {
                                  totaalBouwwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate += onderdeel.Bouwwaarde__c; 
                                  totaalGrondwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate += onderdeel.Grondwaarde__c;
                                  onderdeel.Verkocht__c = true;
                                  onderdeel.Facturatieschijf_aangemaakt__c = true;
                                  onderdelenToUpdate.add(onderdeel);
                              }   
                        }
                        u.Bouwwaarde_Onderdelen__c = totaalBouwwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate;
                        u.Grondwaarde_onderdelen__c = totaalGrondwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate;
                    }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  update onderdelenToUpdate;
}
```

}

where this part is marked in red - no coverage

```
if (onderdelen.Size() > 0) 
                {
                    // Totaal bouwwaarde berekenen   
                    for(Onderdeel__c onderdeel: onderdelen)
                    {
                          if(onderdeel.Unit__c == u.id)
                          {
                              totaalBouwwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate += onderdeel.Bouwwaarde__c; 
                              totaalGrondwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate += onderdeel.Grondwaarde__c;
                              onderdeel.Verkocht__c = true;
                              onderdeel.Facturatieschijf_aangemaakt__c = true;
                              onderdelenToUpdate.add(onderdeel);
                          }   
                    }
                    u.Bouwwaarde_Onderdelen__c = totaalBouwwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate;
                    u.Grondwaarde_onderdelen__c = totaalGrondwaardeOnderdeelVoorUpdate;
                }
```

This is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class UnitTrigger_BeforeUTest 
{
static testMethod void UnitTrigger_UnitWithParts() 
{
       Test.StartTest();

       //Insert project
       Project__c project = new Project__c(Name='test');
       insert project;

       //Insert standaard facturatieschijven voor unit
       Standaard_facturatie_schijf__c SFUnit = new Standaard_Facturatie_schijf__c(name='test',
                                                               Project__c = project.id,
                                                               Percentage_schijf__c = 10,
                                                               Type__c = 'Unit');
       insert SFUnit;

       //Insert standaard facturatieschijven voor unit
       Standaard_facturatie_schijf__c SFUnit2 = new Standaard_Facturatie_schijf__c(name='test',
                                                               Project__c = project.id,
                                                               Percentage_schijf__c = 90,
                                                               Type__c = 'Unit');
       insert SFUnit2;


       //Insert unit
       Unit__c unit = new unit__c(name='test',
                                       Type__c ='Standaard',
                                       Initi_le_VK_Bouw__c=100,
                                       Initi_le_VK_Grond__c=300,
                                       BTW__c = 21,
                                       Project__c=project.id,
                                       Bouwwaarde_appartement__c = 200000,
                                 Bouwwaarde_Onderdelen__c = 10,
                                 Grondwaarde_onderdelen__c = 10);
       insert unit;                                



    //Insert onderdeel
       Onderdeel__c onderdeel = new onderdeel__c (name='test',
                                                   Type__c = 'test',
                                                   Project__c =project.id,
                                                   Bouwwaarde__c = 10000,
                                                   Grondwaarde__c = 10000, 
                                                   Unit__c = unit.Id
                                                 ); 
    insert onderdeel;

    List <Onderdeel__c> onderdelen = [Select id, Bouwwaarde__c, Grondwaarde__c, Unit__c from Onderdeel__c Where Unit__c = :unit.id];  


    update unit; 
    update onderdeel;



    Test.StopTest();
}

static testMethod void UnitTrigger_UnitWithNoParts() 
{
       Test.StartTest();

       //Insert project
       Project__c project = new Project__c(Name='test');
       insert project;

       //Insert standaard facturatieschijven voor unit
       Standaard_facturatie_schijf__c SFUnit = new Standaard_Facturatie_schijf__c(name='test',
                                                               Project__c = project.id,
                                                               Percentage_schijf__c = 10,
                                                               Type__c = 'Unit');
       insert SFUnit;

       //Insert standaard facturatieschijven voor unit
       Standaard_facturatie_schijf__c SFUnit2 = new Standaard_Facturatie_schijf__c(name='test',
                                                               Project__c = project.id,
                                                               Percentage_schijf__c = 90,
                                                               Type__c = 'Unit');
       insert SFUnit2;

       //Insert unit
       Unit__c unit = new unit__c(name='test',
                                       Type__c ='Standaard',
                                       Initi_le_VK_Bouw__c=100,
                                       Initi_le_VK_Grond__c=300,
                                       BTW__c = 21,
                                       Project__c=project.id,
                                       Bouwwaarde_appartement__c = 200000,
                                 Bouwwaarde_Onderdelen__c = 10,
                                 Grondwaarde_onderdelen__c = 10);
       insert unit;                                


    //Insert onderdeel
       Onderdeel__c onderdeel = new onderdeel__c (name='test',
                                                   Type__c = 'test',
                                                   Project__c =project.id,
                                                   Bouwwaarde__c = 10000,
                                                   Grondwaarde__c = 10000 
                                                                         ); 
    insert onderdeel;

    List <Onderdeel__c> onderdelen = [Select id, Bouwwaarde__c, Grondwaarde__c, Unit__c from Onderdeel__c Where Unit__c = :unit.id];      
    update unit;  
    update onderdeel;      
    Test.StopTest();
}
}
```

As you can see I created 2 methods, one where the "onderdelen.Size() > 0" condition is satisfied (in test "UnitTrigger_UnitWithParts")

and 1 method where "onderdelen.Size() > 0" is not satisfied (in test UnitTrigger_UnitWithNoParts())

For some reason I cannot get passed this "onderdelen.Size() > 0" line. I only get 56% coverage.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: First thing would be to have asserts whenever you make any operation to check if it is successful. Without doing any validation with asserts, test class is of no use.

Comment: Also when running a test make sure that this condition is satisfied **Where Unit__c IN:Trigger.newMap.keySet()** with a debug statement. If not, the list onderdelen will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Rahul, would recommend to add asserts in the test class to verify the data that is inserted/updated.

To answer, looking at the code, I assume that the line above `if(onderdelen.Size() > 0)` is not evaluating to true. Hence the below and subsequent lines are not getting executed.

The line I am referring to is

```
if(u.Verkocht__c == true && u.Genereer_facturatieschijven__c == true)
```

As I don't see where these fields `(Verkocht__c & Genereer_facturatieschijven__c )`
are set in the test class

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I set those fields to True on my Unit object in the testclass however, I get 0 % coverage instead of 56 %. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check if the test class is failing or for any error while inserting the record

Comment: thanks so much! it was indeed a failing validation constraint that was preventing the insert from happening. Code coverage is up by 1% now, its not much but i'll take it! thanks alot.

Comment: now everything beneath "if (onderdelen.Size() > 0) " is red. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you put debug and asserts to check whether the child lost isn’t inserted?

Comment: when i put a debug statement in the testclass for the size of the list, i get back 1 element. Which should make onderdelen.Size() > 0 true. Or do I need to add a case where the size is 0 too ?

Comment: Did you put the debug just above the if statement where u are checking list.size()>0

Comment: i found it! i got 100 % coverage now. thanks alot!